# Why am I still getting a CORS Error after enabling CORS

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, fetch

Here is the fetch request :

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/')
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => console.log(data));
    }

    render() {
        return <div></div>;
    }
};
```

This is the backend code :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    next();
});
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ test: 'test' });
});
app.listen(3001, console.log('listeing...'));
```

Error :

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: You should look into the CORS express middleware https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: @Nick I've looked into it. But the examples doesn't resolve the error. app.use(cors()) didn't work either.

Comment: `app.use(cors());` I believe, right?

Comment: yes that's correct.

Comment: It looks like you might have a typo in you're route definition. It should be `app.get('/' ... ` not `app.use(`

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow client to use http methods:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'); // allow client to use http methods
```

Comment: I've tried to allow for the use of http methods and this didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option would be to install the cors package.

install:

```
npm i cors
```

usage:

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```